# Platform specific import in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

My work folder structure is as below,

```
.
├── hello_darwin.py
├── hello_linux.py
├── hello.py
└── hello_windows.py
```

`hello.py` contains common functions, while others contains platform specific code or function, when my module user imports

```
 from hello import common_function, spec_function
```

i need spec_function must be platform specific code, where `spec_funtion` name is masked to its module user.Is there any builting functions to do it or is there any other ways for this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is the [platform](https://docs.python.org/3/library/platform.html) module:

```
import platform

if platform.system().lower().startswith('win'):
    # import windows specific modules
elif platform.system().lower().startswith('lin'):
    # import linux specific modules
elif platform.system().lower().startswith('dar'):
    # import ...
```

Answer (score 3):

```
from sys import plaform
if platform.startswith('win'):
    #windows import
elif platform.startswith('lin'):
    #linux import
elif platform.startswith('dar'):
    #MacOS import
else:
    #some another OS import
```

For more info you can have look at [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#platform)