# Python: Mock a module that does not exist

Tags: python, mocking

I have a large set of legacy python scripts that were developed and used on Linux.
Now the desire is to run parts of this code on Windows without too many changes.

But the code fails on Windows when trying to import Linux specific modules such as `fcntl`.

To be clear, I do not want to run the part of the code that's Linux specific.

Is there any way to use `mock` the modules that simply do not exist?

I tried below approach based on other answers, but it does not work:

main.py

```
import mock
mock.patch.dict('sys.modules', fcntl=mock.MagicMock())
import fcntl
import os
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Platform specific import in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41097265/platform-specific-import-in-python)

Comment: No this does not. My project is very complex hierarchy of hundres of modules. So the import of fcntl is actually coming in from nested modules and it exists in many places. What I wrote in the question is just an attempt to simplify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install a [path finder](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.abc.MetaPathFinder) in the `sys.meta_path` [import hook](https://peps.python.org/pep-0302/) to return a mock object when the given name is `'fcntl'`:

```
import sys
from unittest.mock import MagicMock
from importlib.abc import MetaPathFinder

class MockFcntl(MetaPathFinder):
    def find_spec(self, fullname, target, path=None):
        if fullname == 'fcntl':
            return MagicMock()

sys.meta_path.insert(0, MockFcntl())
```

If your legacy Linux script requires a Python version earlier than 3.3 to run, you can patch the built-in [`__import__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#import__) function instead with a function that loads a mock object into `sys.modules` if the given name is `'fcntl'`:

```
import sys
import builtins
from unittest.mock import MagicMock

def fcntl_mocking_import(name, *args, orig_import=__import__, **kwargs):
    if name == 'fcntl':
        mock = MagicMock()
        sys.modules['fcntl'] = mock
        return mock
    return orig_import(name, *args, **kwargs)

builtins.__import__ = fcntl_mocking_import
```

With either approaches, the code below would run in Windows:

```
from fcntl import flock, LOCK_EX, LOCK_NB

with open(__file__, 'a+') as file:
    flock(file.fileno(), LOCK_EX | LOCK_NB)
```

Note that some modules such as `os` are always automatically imported into the `sys.modules` dictionary by the Python interpreter, in which case you would have to delete its entry with:

```
del sys.modules['os']
```

before you import it with a custom path finder.

Demo: https://ideone.com/MLSnQd

Comment: Thanks blhsing, this worked! But trying to exclude second module does not work...

Comment: What do you mean by excluding a second module? Please clarify with an example.

Comment: For example: trying exclude 'os' module after 'fcntl' using MockOS class does not work. I edited my original question with an example. BTW I am not using python earlier than 3.3.

Comment: The `os` module is always automatically imported into the `sys.modules` dictionary by the Python interpreter so you simply have to do a `del sys.modules['os']` before importing it with a custom path finder. Demo: https://ideone.com/MLSnQd

Comment: Wow. That's cool. Thanks! However some answers seem to suggest that modifying sys is not recommended. Why is that? So how safe is do this in production code